# Snake head in snake game always diagonal to rest of body

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I am trying to create a basic snake game using the arduino UNO along with the MAX72XX module, the LCD module and the analog joystick module. I have made my program using object orientated programming. I have no experience with C++ so I have done really well to get this far in my program (This is the only thing left to help me complete the game!). The only problem that is holding me back is that the snake head is always diagonal to the rest of the body. Here are a few examples of what I mean:

[image]
[image]

Here is my code if the issue is in here (I have commented what part does what):

```
#include "LedControl.h"
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LedControl lc=LedControl(12,10,11,1);
LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 13, 3, 5, 6, 7);


/*lcd->setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd->print(millis() / 1000);*/

class Snake_body//class of each snake body part
{
  //private:




  public:

    int following_direction;
    int x;
    int y;
    int previous_x;
    int previous_y;
    bool enabled;
    /*Snake_body()
    {
      this->enabled = false;
    }*/
    /*Snake_body(int x_value, int y_value) 
    {
      this->enabled = false;
      this->following_direction = 1;
      this->x = x_value;
      this->y = y_value;
      this->previous_y = y_value;
      this->previous_x = x_value;
    }*/
    void configure(int x_value, int y_value)
    {
      //this->enabled = true;
      this->following_direction = 1;
      this->x = x_value;
      this->y = y_value;
      this->previous_y = y_value;
      this->previous_x = x_value;  
    }

};


class Power_up
{
  private:

  public:
    virtual void init() 
    {
      this->x = 0;
      this->y = 0;
    }

    int x;
    int y;
};

Snake_body *snake[64];
int snakes_length;


//Snake_body *snake[0];
Power_up *power_up;

int score;

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);


  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  snakes_length = 1;

  for(int z = 1; z < 64; z++)
  {
    snake[z] = NULL;//makes all snake body parts except head NULL 
  }

  snake[0] = new Snake_body();//define snake head
  snake[0]->configure(0,0);//set it up
  power_up = new Power_up();//power up to increase in body size
  //Snake_body snake[0] = new Snake_body();
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lc.shutdown(0,false);
  /* Set the brightness to a medium values */
  lc.setIntensity(0,8);
  /* and clear the display */
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  score = 0;
  lcd.print("score: ");
  lcd.setCursor(6, 0);
  lcd.print(score);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  power_up->x = random(0, 8);
  power_up->y = random(0, 8);
}

int snake_direction;


void loop() 
{
  int x_axis = analogRead(A0);
  int y_axis = analogRead(A1);
  int switcher = digitalRead(2);


   if(x_axis <= 400)//the following 4 directions are for moving the snake
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 0;
     //x += 1;
     Serial.println("left");
   }


   else if(x_axis >= 600)
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 1;
     //x -= 1;
     Serial.println("right");
   }


   else if(y_axis <= 400)
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 2;
     //y -= 1;
     Serial.println("up");
   }


   else if(y_axis >= 600)
   {
     snake[0]->following_direction = 3;
     //y += 1;
     Serial.println("down");
   }





  if(snake[0]->following_direction == 0 && snake[0]->x < 7)//updates the snakes position
  {
    snake[0]->previous_x = snake[0]->x;
    snake[0]->x += 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0]->following_direction == 1 && snake[0]->x > 0)//updates the snakes position
  {
    snake[0]->previous_x = snake[0]->x;
    snake[0]->x -= 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0]->following_direction == 2 && snake[0]->y > 0)//updates the snakes position
  {
    snake[0]->previous_y = snake[0]->y;
    snake[0]->y -= 1;
  }

  else if(snake[0]->following_direction == 3 && snake[0]->y < 7)//updates the snakes position
  {
    snake[0]->previous_y = snake[0]->y;
    snake[0]->y += 1;
  }








  Serial.println("\n");//USED THESE PRINT STATEMENTS TO PRINT VALUES


  Serial.print("previous x: ");
  Serial.print(snake[0]->previous_x);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("previous y: ");
  Serial.print(snake[0]->previous_y);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("direction: ");
  Serial.print(snake[0]->following_direction);
  Serial.println("\n");




  if(snake[0]->x == power_up->x && snake[0]->y == power_up->y)//if the head collides with the power up
  {
    score += 1;
    lcd.setCursor(6,0);
    lcd.print(score);

    power_up->x = random(0, 8);
    power_up->y = random(0, 8);


    for(int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
    {
      if(snake[j] == NULL)//searches for empty snake body
      {

         snake[j] = new Snake_body();//creates new snake body part
         snake[j]->configure(snake[j-1]->previous_x, snake[j-1]->previous_y);//sets up the snake body part

         snake[j]->following_direction = NULL;
         snakes_length += 1;  
         break;
      }
    }
  }


  for(int i = 1; i < 64; i++)
  {
    if(snake[i] != NULL)//updates the other body parts appart from the snake head (it was updated before this)
    {
      snake[i]->previous_x = snake[i]->x;
      snake[i]->previous_y = snake[i]->y;
      snake[i]->x = snake[i-1]->previous_x;
      snake[i]->y = snake[i-1]->previous_y;    
    }
  }


  lc.setLed(0,power_up->x,power_up->y,true);
  for(int w = 0; w < 64; w++)//drawing body parts onto the screen
  {

    if(snake[w] != NULL)
    {
      lc.setLed(0,snake[w]->x,snake[w]->y,true);
    }
  }





  delay(100); 

  lc.clearDisplay(0);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem well... in the first example the snake body has three straight dots. This means that before the head was straight compared to the body. Only in the screenshot you made it 'turned'  diagonal (?)

Comment: What you can do yourself to 'debug' is to RUN the sketch on a PC. You can do this by creating a class for all Arduino specific classes (like LiquidCrystal, Serial and LedControl) and program all functions (to do nothing or show a simple display, or write just some lines to mimic the output). This will let you easily add break points and step through your code, or see a (long) list of output including history.

Comment: And some OO improvements (you did already a good job): you don't have to use the 'new'/dynamic way of allocating in your case, just create elements directly. The normal naming for classes is PascalCasing thus PowerUp instead of Power_up, and make all variables in a class private (move the `private`  keyword before `int x; ` in the Power_up class. Instead of `snake[0]->y += 1;` you can use `snake[0]-y++`, similar with --.

Comment: When a new snake body part is added, let the sketch print out it's position. Check, if that position is correct. I see you are adding the new element at the previous position of the last one, but then you let every part (except for the head) move one step further. Please try to move the adding part to after the body updating part

Comment: @MichelKeijzers No the snake can only move vertically and horizontally. In the picture it is moving in a straight line. But for example if the snake's body was on x axis 5 and the snake head was on x axis 4 and if both of their y axis' get moved up by one then their x would be on the same x axis as before but the head would be one place higher than the body.

Comment: @chrisl tried putting the adding a new snake part after updating. No luck.

Comment: Then please print the position of the new added element. Show the complete Serial output

Comment: @chrisl I have had an idea! Could I use the previous direction of the snake head and use the current direction to determine which way the snake turned and then fix the head using the x and y axis' from there.

Comment: @chrisl does not matter I fixed the game myself. All that I did was move the previous_x and previous_y out of the if statements

Comment: @MichelKeijzers does not matter I fixed the game myself. All that I did was move the previous_x and previous_y out of the if statements

Comment: Then please write an answer yourself, so that others might profit from your learning and that this question can be marked as answered by yourself.

Comment: Glad you sorted it out yourself. If you have more complicated problems in the future, consider trying some non-Arduino specific parts on a PC, with full debugging capabilities.

Comment: when debugging a problem such as yours, it is important to identify the failure correctly .... you say that the head is diagonal from the body ... but that is not what the actual problem is ... the head is not offset at a diagonal, it is offset by one square to left or to right